# F5 Load Balancer : Firewall and server shows source as client machine IP not F5 IP

Tags: network, f5

We have two standalone Weblogic instances(On AIX Environment) Load balanced by an F5 Load Balancer.

From a client machine we are running a Java Utility which makes JNDI call to one of the ejb's deployed on the app servers. This call uses a t3 protocol and connects to the F5 IP.

If we do netstat at the individual application server, it shows connections from client machine and not from F5. Also Firewall logs show the source of connections to the application server as the IP of the client machine and not F5.

To test if the connection from Utility machine to servers was being routed through F5 and not directly to individual servers, we created a rule in the Firewall to block connections to individual server IP’s. On applying this rule the utilities could no longer make JNDI Connections.

My Utility is not aware of the individual application server IP's. My question is this: Is the above behavior correct? Or does it mean that the connections are in fact being made directly to individual application servers? If not then why is the source IP coming as the IP of the client machine?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loadbalancing on F5 can work this way, if you configured it to do so, but without any configuration details it's impossible to tell if that's the case here.

In many cases seeing the actual IP address on the backend nodes is preferred, for example when generating visitor statistics or when implementing IP access lists.

Comment: Thanks, we found that the F5 LB was indeed configured this way.

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour for F5 Virtual Servers is not to NAT the client source address.  You can configure SNAT Automap on the Virtual Server and this will translate the client address to the outgoing interface of the F5.

Answer (score 2):

On the F5 you can run `tmsh show sys connection` to display ltm connections. This will output the following information that will be useful for finding out what the F5 actually does:

- cs-client-addr - the (client) source IP address on the clientside of the connection
- cs-client-port - the (client) source port on the clientside of the connection
- cs-server-addr - the (server) destination IP address on the clientside of the connection (i.e. the Virtual Server IP address)
- cs-server-port - the (server) destination port on the clientside of the connection (i.e. the Virtual Server port)
- ss-client-addr - the (client) source IP address on the serverside of the connection (i.e. the SNAT address)
- ss-client-port - the (client) source port on the serverside of the connection (i.e. the SNAT port)
- ss-server-addr - the (server) destination IP address on the serverside of the connection (i.e., the Pool Member address)
- ss-server-port - the (server) destination port on the serverside of the connection (i.e., the Pool Member port)